# Cannot Mount Synology disk raid 10 on ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: mount, raid, mdadm

I'm trying to mount my 4x4TB disks with btrfs file system and raid 10 from a Synology NAS that won't start.
I've followed this guide from Synology kb:
https://kb.synology.com/sv-se/DSM/tutorial/How_can_I_recover_data_from_my_DiskStation_using_a_PC
All the pre-requisite are satisfied so I've mounted my four disks on a tower pc, run live Ubuntu 20.04.3 desktop from usb key and write the command from the guide.

Installed mdadm and lvm2, all ok.

`root@ubuntu:~# mdadm -Asf && vgchange -ay mdadm: /dev/md/2 has been started with 4 drives.`

Seems to work (lvs have no output):

`root@ubuntu:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid10]
md2 : active raid10 sda3[0] sdd3[3] sdb3[2] sdc3[1]
7804393088 blocks super 1.2 64K chunks 2 near-copies [4/4] [UUUU]

unused devices: 
root@ubuntu:~# lvs`

The mount passage didn't work:

`root@ubuntu:~# mount /dev/md2 /home/ubuntu/test -o ro mount: /home/ubuntu/test: can't read superblock on /dev/md2.`

Don't know why. Health of the disks is excellent, all are recognized, active with superblock persistent...so why Ubuntu can't read it?
Thanks in advance for the support on this.

Comment: is there any useful content in [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/318018/how-to-set-up-and-get-started-with-your-synology-nas/)? I used it to help set up my Synology NAS using SAMBA and cifs to achieve it with appropriate entries in fstab. I also found the [Synology Forum](https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/1) quite helpful.

Comment: I didn't find anything helpful for my case. The Synology NAS is broken and I'm trying to recover data from 4 disks on a PC as suggested by Synology but it didn't work. I've write also on Synology forum, hope this helps.